# Is it possible to set up a VPN server on Debian 8 while keeping my web services (php/apache)?

Tags: web, debian, vpn

I would like to set up a VPN server, however it means ipv4 forwarding. Is it possible to set up a VPN without shutting down web services or should i use 2 separate servers ?

Thanks for reading ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting up a VPN server should not affect your web services. The only limitation is that you cannot use an HTTP(S) port (80 or 443), which I personally find practical (I have already seen Wi-Fi hotspots blocking all the ports except 80 and 443). However, if you get along with another port, you will do fine.

There is a good article about setting up an OpenVPN server on Debian Wiki ([here](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN)). I have managed to set up the server using only this article.

Wishing you good luck.